# Remove values in one data frame based upon cell reference in another data frame

Tags: r

I'm sure this is simple but cannot find an answer for it. I have a data frame df:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:10,1000,rep=TRUE)))
```

I then have another smaller data frame that has cell references (row and column numbers) referring to specific cells in df that should be empty (i.e. NA):

```
cellRefs <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(1:10,10,rep=TRUE)))
```

How do I go about replacing all the cells in df with NA that are referred to by the row and column references from cellRefs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could convert the 'cellRefs' into a `matrix` and use as row/column index to assign those elements in 'df' to NA

```
df[as.matrix(cellRefs)] <- NA
```

Comment: Nice. A simple solution. It is a shame that I still seem to be stuck thinking like the other solution for all things R :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the fastest way, but it works with a loop across cellRefs rows.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(cellRefs)){
  df[cellRefs[i,1],cellRefs[i,2]] = NA
}
```

Comment: No that doesn't work - it only gets rid of the very first cell in df referred to in cellRefs. I did just modify the cellRefs above to ensure it gets a proper cell reference (i.e. not a 0 for row or column!).

Comment: Yeap sorry my bad, forgot to switch the 1 for an i, I edited my answer and gave the correct way

Comment: Nice one! Thank you so much for your help! :)